# How can i use module federation with nextjs 14

Tags: webpack-module-federation, next.js14

I can`t find any example on how to use module federation with nextjs 14 (with typescript).

Has someone an example on how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

```
1 )first need to install all dependency

npm install webpack webpack-cli @next/bundle-analyzer @next/dynamic @next/webpack-5 typescript ts-loader

2) create a tsconfig file and add the setings

// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2017"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "strict": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "jsxImportSource": "@emotion/react"
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

3) now in webpack  config file need to add 

const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "app1",
      library: { type: "var", name: "app1" },
      remotes: {
        app2: "app2",
      },
      shared: ["react", "react-dom"],
    }),
  ],
};


4) and finally in the componet file
// pages/index.tsx
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const App2Component = dynamic(() => import('app2/App'), {
  loading: () => <p>Loading...</p>,
});

function HomePage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>App1</h1>
      <App2Component />
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomePage;
```